# Map an array of objects to another with multiple rows being similar in node express

Tags: node.js, mapping, dto

I'm attempting to map an object to another, and I'm having trouble writting the loop correctly. Basically:

I have 1 object returned by my repository level. It has multiple rows based on the same username but with scores based on different courses thus:

```
row1 = userName Tim, courseScore 5 
row2 = userName Tim, otherCourseScore 10 
row3 = userName Mike, courseScore 4 
row4 = userName Mike, otherCourseScore 7
```

and so on. I'd like to map this to a DTO object so that the data looks like this:

```
row1 = userName Tim, courseScore 5, otherCourseScore 10
row2 = userName Mike, courseScore 4, otherCourseScore 7
```

I'm having trouble writing the a loop that can go through the first object and map it to the DTO level. Here's what I currently have, but it's not mapping the data correctly.

```
for (let key in UserInformation) {
  let usr = UserInformation[key].userName;
  if (usr === UserInformation[key].userName) {
      userScatterplotDTO.userName = UserInformation[key].userName;
      userScatterplotDTO.judgmentScore = UserInformation[key].score;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
let rows = [{
    userName: 'Tim',
    type: 'courseScore',
    score: 5
  },
  {
    userName: 'Tim',
    type: 'otherCourseScore',
    score: 10
  },
  {
    userName: 'Mike',
    type: 'courseScore',
    score: 4
  },
  {
    userName: 'Mike',
    type: 'otherCourseScore',
    score: 7
  }
];

let result = {

}

rows.forEach((row) => {
  if (!(result[row.userName])){
    result[row.userName] = {
      userName: row.userName,
      scores: []
    };
  }
  result[row.userName].scores.push({
    type: row.type,
    score: row.score
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: having an initial state, then modifying it and finally returning a final state. It look like a [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) to me